# Elementary "loses track" of the screen brightness after standby

Tags: release-loki, brightness

This is a minor issue and I am unsure how to fix it. Sometimes when I boot back up from standby mode, the screen turns on at full brightness. When I press the key combination to lower the brightness, the brightness popover thinks the brightness is at its lowest value, and it does not let me lower the brightness. I have to first press the brightness increase key combination *then* start lowering the brightness again. Is there a fix for this?

I have a Dell E6410 laptop with automatic brightness disabled. I'm running on 0.4.1 Loki. Would it be fixed if I upgrade to Juno?

Comment: Hi Kevin, when you adjust the brightness, do you see an on-screen-display showing the brightness in the upper-righthand corner? If there's nothing showing the adjustment but the brightness itself, you might not have Linux support for controlling it. It also might be helpful if you run `ls /sys/class/backlight/` in a terminal and see whether it looks like there's software control for the brightness of your laptop. There should be a folder for it, with various files for the current brightness, etc.

Comment: Yes, there is usually an on-screen display for the brightness level in the upper righthand corner. In the `/sys/class/backlight/` directory, there is two other directories: `acpi_video0` and `nv_backlight`. Should I just be checking the values of the current brightness if it fails to adjust brightness next time?

Comment: Yeah, I'd go into the `nv_backlight` directory and make sure the values in it are changing based on when you control the brightness with the keyboard. Another suggestion: I'd go into Settings -> Power -> Brightness and see whether the slider works, and maybe turn off "Automatically Adjust Brightness" if it's on.